# Print between two patterns with filepath/filename in a directory

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, find

I need a command that prints data between two strings (Hello and End) along with the file name and file path on each line. Here is the input and output. Appreciate your time and help

Input 
**file1:**

```
    Hello
    abc
    xyz
    End
```

**file2:**

```
    Hello
    123
    456
    End
```

**file3:**

```
    Hello
```

**Output:**

```
    /home/test/seq/file1 abc
    /home/test/seq/file1 xyz
    /home/test/seq/file2 123
    /home/test/seq/file2 456
```

I tried awk and sed but not able to print the file with the path.
`awk '/Hello/{flag=1;next}/End/{flag=0}flag' * 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It can be done with sed, but the solution is complicated. Could you post the sed code you've tried, that solves as much of the problem as you can?

Comment: The below command prints the content but along with two strings which i don't want and also do not print the filename with path.
sed -n '/Hello/,/End/p'

Comment: The sed solution is pretty advanced; you'd probably better use another tool, like awk.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk '!/Hello/ && !/End/ {print FILENAME,$0} ' /home/test/seq/file?
```

Output:

```
/home/test/seq/file1 abc
/home/test/seq/file1 xyz
/home/test/seq/file2 123
/home/test/seq/file2 456
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I used the {print FILENAME,$0} to my awk command that I posted in my original post and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains lines above `Hello` and/or below `End`, then you can use a flag to control printing as you had attempted in your question, e.g.

```
awk -v f=0 '/End/{f=0} f == 1 {print FILENAME, $0} /Hello/{f=1}' file1 file2 file..
```

This would handle the case where your input file contained, e.g.

```
$cat file
some text
some more
Hello
abc
xyz
End
still more text
```

The flag `f` is a simple ON/OFF flag to control printing and placing the `end` rule first with the actual print in the middle eliminates the need for any `next` command.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using the astrisk "*" to search in all files within directory instead of giving filenames like file1 file2 file3 in your post. Is there a way awk can do a recursive search  with subfolders and print the filename and path?

Comment: Sure, just use `'*'` for your `file file1 file2 ....` e.g. `awk -v f=0 '/End/{f=0} f == 1 {print FILENAME, $0} /Hello/{f=1}' *`